# IntelliJ+Android+Git+Bitbucket - How to sync project on two separate PCs?

Tags: android, git, github, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am developing an Android app and would like to achieve the following:
I am working on two PCs: one at home and one at work. I would like to have the project in sync on these PCs. So I am writing code at work on my work PC, and when I go home and fire up my IntelliJ IDE, to see all those things I wrote at work and continue from there.
Now, I know this can be done via Git and Bitbucket/GitHub. The problem is that I never used Git, and I am new to IntelliJ also (switched from Eclipse). Can someone please explain how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: At end of work always commit and push all changes to remote server (bitbucket). After this in new location pull changes from remote server. This is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is just to have your workspace in a dropbox or google drive directory. It will automatically sync anything you do.

GIT and SVN are version control, and not really made for this. They are rather made to have a separation between your local development, and a, possibly live, working version.

I'd suggest you start off with using dropbox as a workspace, since it will solve your problem with syncing. 
If you never used GIT, it might be easier to start off with Subversion (SVN). GIT or SVN, either way you will want to do some research of your own what they are for and how to use them. Most IDEs give you proper plugins so this shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite complicated to answer Your question in just a few words, especially when You do not have any experience with mentioned tools.

What I advice You is:

1. Learn what is it Git and how does it work. You will find tutorials here: https://www.atlassian.com/git and here: http://git-scm.com/book.
2. Practice alot with Git basic commands, local and remote repositories, commits and so on.
3. Learn how IntelliJ communicates with Git repositories.
4. Ask whenever You get stuck.

Good luck